# Cannot appendChild to a null or undefined variable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**Background**

I am extremely new to javascript and HTML and come from a data-oriented python and R background albeit not particularly advanced.
I decided I'd try to build a chrome extension to fit a particular need I have and teach myself some js and HTML along the way.
Its basic function is to pull the title of the current page and then send this as a query to a newsapi which then returns a json that I can display in the popup html.

**Problems**

The errors for this specific part of my code refer to its inability to appendChild to a null or undefined variable. I have been trying to figure out this part for quite a while and have learned a lot about the asynchronicity of js, callback, promises and whatnot but so far have been unable to implement a fix.

To be honest I probably have this coded all wrong and maybe implementing it in the wrong way but I am not knowledgable enough to perceive this.

Any help with this would be great, even if it just references for further reading!

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
      var tabTITLE = tabs[0].title ;   
      console.log(tabTITLE)
      const apiKey = 'mykey'
      let topic = tabTITLE;
      let url = `https://gnews.io/api/v4/search?q=${tabTITLE}&token=${apiKey}`
      console.log(url)
      fetch(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            data.articles.forEach(article =>{
                const newsList = document.querySelector('.news-list');
                let li = document.createElement('li');
                let a = document.createElement('a');
                a.setAttribute('href', article.url);
                a.setAttribute('target','_blank');
                a.textContent = article.title;
                li.appendChild(a);
                newsList.appendChild(li);
            })
        })
    });

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <link 
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>News</title>
    </head>
    <body> 
      <h3>Links</h3>
     <div class="container">
        <ul class="news-list"></ul>
     </div>
     <script src = "index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Means `querySelector` does not find the element

Comment: you can probably see this happening if you throw a `debugger` statement in your `forEach`

Comment: `newsList` is null.

Comment: @connexo not all the time. The page OP is fetching from could have it.

Comment: What is `data` when you log it?

Comment: @Rojo data appears as the .json received from the gnewsapi.

Comment: Your `querySelector`s need to be in a [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/)